# How to make Mean curvature flow skeleton deterministic after every run?

Tags: cgal

When I run mean curvature flow skeletonization from cgal the resulting skeleton is always a bit different. I was wondering if there is a way to make the skeleton exact after each run (with fixed skeleton parameters ofcourse).  Can some one point me to piece of code where this happens and I would like to fix this issue.

I saw someone post similar question earlier but the answer did not contain where exactly in cgal causes this problem. Here's [a link](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Mean-curvature-flow-skeleton-td4664031.html) to that discussion.

Comment: Grepping around it does not seems to be relevant maps/hash-maps. If you want to have a look at it, I think you should look at the intermediate output of the algorithm to identify which part exactly is not deterministic. For example start by looking if the meso-skeleton is the same at each iteration step from different runs.

Comment: I am too lazy to test it myself, but is it nondeterministic for both Polyhedron_3 and Surface_mesh?